# jQuery Input-Mask Changing Date Value on Conversion

Tags: jquery, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I'm using jquery input-mask and programmatically pulling data from a database to fill in a field when I'm returning to a form after having filled it in.

The data seems to be coming in ok (as in up until the point the data gets into the field it is correct). However when the plugin kicks in, it changes the date from my lovely correct data in a timestamp format to the correct format but some random date from 2010 or thereabouts I've also gone into the future to 2040 and 2050 sometimes.

If I turn off the input-mask the correct date is passed in. If I catch the data before the input mask is run it is correct. if input mask gets it's grubby hands on it it changes the date. Doesn't seem to be a rhyme or reason to it.

I'm using multiple instances on the page and my current plan of attack is stripping out everything else to get a clean version of this to work out the issue.

There's a lot going on on the page and this will take me several hours so after not finding any joy at the input-mask site I figured I'd post here in the off chance someone has run into this before and can give me one of those "oh yeah you just need to do this," comments.

Edit for an example of code:

```
// Datemask Initialization dd/mm/yyyy
$(".datemask-details").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});

// html 
<input type="text" class="form-control datemask-details" data-mask data-inputmask="alias: 'dd/mm/yyyy'" name="start" id="start" />
```

I'm using ColdFusion to pull in the value which comes as a timestamp from the database: "2016-01-01 00:00:00.0"

Nothing about this method has failed in past uses, just this time and I'm suspecting the multiple instances as the only really different issue here. But if it is just a mismatch I'd be a lot happier. Your thoughts also got me figuring I should try to check for extra white space.

Answer (score 0):

This post belongs as a comment, but I cannot comment yet. Can you post your inputmask code for the datetime and an example of what's coming from the database for that field? I suspect there is a format mismatch which is causing your interesting results.